# How to order mysql results by column priority?

Tags: mysql

How to order mysql results by column priority?

Example. I have a table of products, the table contains two columns, product name (p.name) and product description (p.desc).

Users should be able to enter keywords to find products in the database.

```
"p.name LIKE '%keyword%' OR p.desc LIKE '%keyword%'
```

I want the results that match p.name returned first and the p.desc second.

How would I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would try something like

```
ORDER BY (NOT (p.name LIKE '%keyword%'))
```

If your first condition is satisfied, `order by` clause will evaluate to `false`. Thus, such records will be pushed ahead.

**edit**
Equals sign (`=`) has probably got into the question by mistake.

Comment: GREAT ANSWER! Took me a minute to figure out what you were doing with the logic. I'm used to ORDER BY strictly specifying columns. I made a tiny modification to the code, I changed it to "ORDER BY p.desc LIKE '%keyword%'". This provides the same results and does not require the NOT statement. Thanks!

Comment: @payling: actually Nikita's version is better, because it will still sort rows with matching p.name first, even if p.desc is also matching in same row.

Comment: @ Mchl, true. I could also do "ORDER BY p.name LIKE '%keyword%' DESC" if I was concerned about the order of matching rows. This replicates the results of Nikitia's code exactly and for me is a bit more readable.

Comment: "Thus, such records will be pushed ahead." - Why, though?

Answer (score 1):

You should try MySQL Full Text Search as in [`MATCH() ... AGAINST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) and more [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html). Then order by the search rank with the columns.